# Where are logs located while running NUnit?

Tags: nunit, resharper, nlog

I'm running NUnit tests from Resharper. I want to track execution process so my question is where can I find logs produced by my application?

I use NLog, logger output path is relative, e.g. `logs\mylog.txt`.

Comment: Try looking in "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\ReSharper\v5.1\Bin\ and C:\Documents and Settings\myusername\Local Settings\Temp\somestrangedirname.qrm\MyProjectName\assembly\dl3\682fe265\0e147688_509ccb01 (or similar name). This ought to be the most likely places (the executing assembly directory and the calling assembly directory).

Comment: BTW if you store your ReSharper files in each project directory you have to look there instead of in the temp directory.

Answer (score 6):

I have a similar setup with my current project and for the unit tests, my NLog output goes to \UnitTests\bin\Debug\Logs. The logger is set up as follows in NLog.config (this produces a daily log file):

```
<target name="FileLog" xsi:type="File" fileName="${basedir}/logs/${shortdate}_log.txt"
```

If you aren't getting any output at all from NLog, try adding the throwExceptions, internalLogLevel and internalLogFile attributes to your NLog.config like this:

```
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      throwExceptions="true"
      internalLogLevel="Debug"
      internalLogFile="nlog_log.log">
```

I realise this is an old question but just in case you haven't found the answer yet, I though I would see if this helps.