# TFS build server creates no test results

Tags: testing, logging, tfs, build

Is there any way to activate a test related log at our TFS build server?
If a tests fails, I can't find any information about it (besides the name of the test).

I checked:

- The drop folder. There is the normal log, but this log ends after the compilation, so before the tests are checked
- The compilation folder at the build server (C:\Builds\8...). There is a folder "Test Results" next to the "bin" and the "src" folder, but the "Test Results" folder is always empty.
- The build definition. Couldn't find any option to activate a log regarding tests.

When i check the build in the web view, all I see is:

x/y test(s) passed, z failed, 0 inconclusive

No Code Coverage Results
Other Errors and Warnings
z+1 error(s), 0 warning(s)

Failed z1
Failed z2
...
Failed zn
Test Run Failed.

How can I find further information, why the tests are failing?

We are using:

- TFS 2012 + a TFS 2012 build server
- Rolling builds
- Visual Studio 2013 + Resharper at our local machines
- NUnit + MOQ
- Rolling builds (no more than 30 minutes) build definition

Comment: have you got diagnostics set in your build def? >Process>Basic>Logging Verbosity. I'm not sure if this helps with tests failing but it's worth a go.

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer. I changed it from "Normal" to "Diagnostic" and the log is much more detailed now. However, the information in the log still ends after the warnings (at the end of the compilation), before the tests are executed.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4438614/where-are-logs-located-while-running-nunit <- might help, nunit's not my thing, although I'd be tempted to seach for *.log under C:\Builds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We got rid of the problem after we upgraded to **TFS 2015.**
Now I just have to check the web interface, if a build is broken because of a unit test I click at the specific build to open the detail view of it. At the right side there is an area named **Test result,** where I can click at a link to get to the **Test Run** page. **Under Attachments (1)** I got a file of the type **Visual Studio Test Results File**, which shows me exactly what the problem was.